# INDEX and MATCH functions with external file

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to get around the issue of looking up values based on more than 1 criteria. It didn't seem like VLOOKUP was going to work, so I've tried the following with MATCH used to concatenate the 2 values I'm looking up.

```
=INDEX('A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx'!$B$2:$E$91,MATCH(1,('A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx'!$B$2:$E$91="Helpfulness")*('A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx'!$B$2:$E$91=$A5)),3)
```

If I do Ctrl+Shift+Enter, I'm getting the error

> value is not available to the formula or function

Without CSE, I get

> Value used in formula is of the wrong data type"

and #VALUE error.

I'm sure I'm just missing an obvious trick here but been racking my brain for hours.

As you can see from image, the same name can appear many times for different categories (Lookup name is represented by $A5 and be dragged down).

## Data I'm trying to look up.

[image: Data I'm trying to look up.]

## EDIT: added actual lookup data.

[image: EDIT: added actual lookup data.]

## EDIT:Formula evaluation which doesn't look right

[image: EDIT:Formula evaluation which doesn't look right]

Comment: MATCH only works on a single row/column/vector. You are passing a multiple dimension array to it.

Comment: You also appear to be missing worksheet names in your reference, unless you've somehow exceeded the 31 character sheet name limitation.

Comment: Sorry, I had the file open so the reference omitted the sheet name. Full formula: =INDEX('P:\Daily Agent Stats\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$B$2:$E$91,MATCH(1,('P:\Daily Agent Stats\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$B$2:$E$91="Helpfulness")&('P:\Daily Agent Stats\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$B$2:$E$91=$A5)),3)

Comment: I've seen someone use a multi-dimension array in a more local formula:=INDEX(A1:G55,MATCH(1,(B:B=J2)*(C:C=J3),0),7) so I substituted the local ranges for my external range.

Comment: Yes but see how each one is only one column not 4 `B:B` and `C:C` vs. `$B$2:$E$91`  Limit it to the column to check.

Comment: Ah got it! I've amended to:
=INDEX('P:\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$B$2:$E$91,MATCH(1,('P:\Daily Agent Stats\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$B$2:$B$91="Helpfulness")*('P:\Daily Agent Stats\[A2D Daily Factor Percentage Report-2018-09-07.xlsx]A2D Daily Factor Percentage Rep'!$C$2:$C$91=$A5)),3)
but now I'm getting a 0 value returned where the value should be '1' meaning 100% for the very first row.

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  It is an array formula.

Comment: Did you remember to array enter? And is the 1 in column D?

Comment: Yes, I hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter - otherwise I get an error. And the 1 is in Column D - specifically D2.

Comment: Without actually see the data, it is hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Added a couple of screenshots. Hope it helps in figuring out what could be going wrong here. I dragged the formula down and it's giving same result for other names also.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas, or perhaps another solution to looking up data based on 2 criteria in an external file?